# how to find if a network interface is mobile with java

Tags: java, networking

I need to find if the active network interface using Windows 7 is a USB modem or if it is a typical Ethernet interface.

Is there any way to do this using Java?

Comment: @RomanC What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You can list the [network interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) and maybe use [isPointToPoint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/parameters.html) or perhaps something else in the [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) class to detect the modem connection.

Comment: I tried isPointToPoint but didn't work. I haven't found anything useful to solve this issue in the NetWorkInterface class so far. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: out of curiosity, what didn't work with is PointToPoint? Did it return false for all interfaces?

Comment: It returned false for the interface asociated with the USB modem